# How to stop prettier from formating { 'field': value } to {field: value}

Tags: formatting, prettier

This is my prettier config, I'm new to prettier so dont judge me
How to fix that thing?

```
module.exports = {
trailingComma: 'es5',
tabWidth: 4,
semi: false,
singleQuote: true,
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier removes single quotes when saving JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75872797/prettier-removes-single-quotes-when-saving-javascript-files)